Physical exercise
Do you know of any ancient-or-modern formally-Buddhist sources which recommend personal physical exercise -- for physical and/or mental well-being?
Because I'm not sure I do, except only maybe very tenuously:

to help stay awake
walking as a side-effect of the alms round
East Asian abbots, might be inclined to include work in the daily routine.

It seems to me that exercise is recommended and beneficial -- from personal experience, and according to modern medical propaganda.
So maybe it's surprising if it is nowhere in Buddhist doctrine -- including for lay-people?


Monks, there are these five benefits of walking up & down. What five?
One is fit for long journeys; one is fit for striving; one has little
disease; that which is eaten, drunk, chewed, tasted, goes through
proper digestion; the composure (samādhi) attained by walking up & down is
long-lasting.
These, monks, are the five benefits of walking up & down
Note

Cankama: Walking meditation, usually in the form of walking back and forth along a prescribed path. [— jtb]

AN 5.29


Thank you -- physical health, samādhi too.


.... Unsuitable activity is a roadblock for health. Bad friendship is
a roadblock for ethical conduct. Lack of sense restraint is a
roadblock for the spiritual life. ....
.... Suitable activity nourishes health. Good friendship nourishes
ethical conduct. Sense restraint nourishes the spiritual life. ....
AN 10.73

The above sutta does not explain what "suitable activity" nourishes health, but presumably it's exercise (AN 5.29 from Dhamma Dhatu's answer) and good diet (SN 3.13).

What is the advantage of often reviewing this: ‘I am liable to get
sick, I am not exempt from sickness’? There are sentient beings who,
drunk on the vanity of health, do bad things by way of body, speech,
and mind. Reviewing this subject often, they entirely give up the
vanity of health, or at least reduce it.
AN 5.57

While taking care of health by good diet and good physical activity is important, it should not lead to vanity of health. The above sutta shows the contemplation to avoid vanity of health.

See AN 3.16 https://lucid24.org/an/main/an03/index.html#3.16
throughout the day and night, the recommended practice is to walk and sit (meditation). Walking is mentioned first. Ajahn Mun, famous patriarch of forest thai tradition, would walk 1 to 2 hours first thing when he woke up.
monks during ancient times had to walk on alms round to get food from where they normally stay, which good be pretty good exercise on uneven terrain.
But yes, even with all that, I would also agree that there's a lack of emphasis of physical exercise in early Buddhism.

I think there is a misunderstanding w.r.t. the level of physical activity in the modern era vis-à-vis ancient times. Even the Buddha was known to had travelled great distances to many places (by foot) in his lifetime in order to spread his teachings to as wide an audience as possible.
Another potential misunderstanding is that the Buddha and his monks only do meditation all day with hardly any physical activity. When staying in one place, the Buddha and his monks are known to travel certain distances daily for their alms as mentioned in Bāhiya Sutta.

“The Blessed One has gone into town for alms.”

It is unlikely that a day goes by that the Buddha or any of his monks don’t do distance walking (perhaps easily more than an hour a day). Likewise, physical activities should be very common for Buddhist lay supporters then. Many of them are either farmers, hunter-gathers or town-folks who are engaged in one form of physical activities (e.g. craftmanship) or another. So, recommendations to do physical exercise would appear strange to people then. I think the recommendations to do physical exercise are more suited to our modern society due to the prevalence of a sedentary lifestyle today. I suspect this is the reason why there is hardly any mention about the benefits of physical activities in the sutras.

Perhaps. But there are many and detailed references to "eating" for example, and so I find it strange they wouldn't explicitly mention exercise as well. I think of the three -- i.e. food, rest, and work -- as being related, and so it's strange to talk about just one (food) in isolation. I get that food is a requisite -- perhaps on the contrary, Buddhism even advises against exercise or sport, as being (at a minimum) unseemly for a monk, so... Another reason might be if Buddhism promotes a "mind-only" view. Or if it's because not everybody with age can exercise, and the Dhamma is for everyone.

A few centuries after Buddhism became the established religion, I think that many of the (wealthy) Buddhist lay supporters were urban "merchants", while the "peasants" were Hindu. I don't know what their lifestyle was, I only imagine it was like today's, probably with house-servants.

You could be right. I think in the past only the wealthy folks get well-fed. The rest probably had certain degrees of malnourishment.and led very tough lives with few enjoying longevity.

That's so by definition if "wealthy" means "having enough to eat" -- e.g. the kind of folk who could support monks' alms rounds. I read that this was after the "second urbanization" began -- i.e. iron age (and clearing forests), kings, tax collectors, rice paddies -- contemporary with Socrates.

As far as I know there are no physical exercises mentioned for physical or mental well being. I do not know why such a thing is expected to be told from the mouth of Buddha!!!
The cure to suffering lies in renunciation of cravings including the craving for well being. When you go mad you let it be and recognise that mind is mad. When mind is healthy you let it be and recognise that mind is healthy. We try to cure the body but ultimately you have to realise that body itself is suffering and you must renounce it as self and that which is not you or yours or yourself , what should you do with it ? For example - what should you do with a broken light bulb ? Just leave it as it is. Don’t concentrate on it.
Find out what is bothering you next. Is it feelings ? Is it perceptions? Is it choices ? Is it consciousness? Is it money ? Is it progress ? Is it your boss? Etc etc Just leave it as it is. Don’t worry about it. Find out what is bothering you next. And so on. It is crucial to know the Art of leaving as it is. Sometimes it itches. Just leave it as it is. Recognise it is itching.
The entire philosophy of Buddha is different. So no physical exercises for health reasons. It is a different ball game which requires stillness and not action.

Dhammapada 204 (whose back-story advices moderation in eating) has the Buddha saying e.g. "Health is the greatest gift" -- as if that matters? And the back-story seems to recognize a mind-body connection -- which other suttas do too, w.r.t. eating -- in e.g. advice to a king. It's strange to me because I consider exercise as a "requisite" -- i.e. for health -- the difference being that one might "take" exercise whereas one is "given" other requisites.

Wouldn't deliberately avoiding or restricting exercise or sport, be almost like an ascetic or unhealthy practice, of the sort the Buddha didn't approve of when he decided on the Middle Way instead -- i.e. an extreme?

@ChrisW We only do what is necessary. Mind is superior to body. Mind must prevail. We should practice Dhamma for days , months and years in a meditating position while trying to achieve stillness. No amount of medicine or exercise can help escape suffering but Dhamma can.
